# What is the use of TelephoneNumberUtil class?

Tags: android, phone-number, telephony

I want to know the basic use of `TelephoneNumberUtil` class in Android. I searched on that but in the Android I'm not able to get a proper answer. Can anyone explain me the exact use of this class?

Comment: There's no class `TelephoneNumberUtil` in Android SDK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a [formatter for international phone numbers](http://www.chinaup.org/docs/migrating/m5-0.9/changes/pkg_android.telephony.html).

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"Status Code:404 Not Found"*.

Comment: Here's a [cached page copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20101005022611/http://www.chinaup.org/docs/migrating/m5-0.9/changes/pkg_android.telephony.html) from Internet Archive. It says that `TelephoneNumberUtil` class was removed in SDK v0.9.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils) `public class PhoneNumberUtils` contains

> various utilities for dealing with phone number strings

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**

Format an international telephone number.

**Detailed Answer**

if you have number `1234567890` and you need format it US number format 
to be like this

`123-456-7890`

then you should use [formatNumber](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber(java.lang.String)) method

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumbe(yourPhoneString);
```

**Notice** this method deprecated use instead  *[formatNumber (String phoneNumber, 
                String defaultCountryIso)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))*

Reference

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html